# Cannot load my CSV file into my R? keep getting error messages

Tags: r, file, csv, load

So basically I succesfully exported my SQL view data into a csv file. but no when I load into Rgui software, I get the following errror:

```
> load("C:\\Users\\dachen\\Documents\\vTargetBuyers.csv")
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘vTargetBuyers.csv’ has magic number 'Marit'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

What should I do? Is it the R version installed wrong? or something wrong with my CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `read.csv` instead of `load`.  `load` is for reading files created by `save`.

Type `?read.csv` to access the documentation.

Comment: Hey thanks! I will accept your answer. Also do you mind email me? just getting started on R, and i have few short questions that maybe you can answer. Please consider helping me! gethbonow at gmail

Comment: Hey thanks! I will accept your answer. Also do you mind email me? just getting started on R, and i have few short questions that maybe you can answer. Please consider helping me! gethbonow at gmail. Can I ask what's your email?